# Return Statement Error - Parsing IP Address String

Tags: c#, string

Can anyone tell me why my last return statement does not work?

```
public class IpAddress
{
    private String dottedDecimal;
    private int[] Octet= new int[4];
    public int i;

    //Default constructor
    public IpAddress()
    {
        dottedDecimal = "0.0.0.0";
        for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
        {
            Octet[i] = 0;  //setting the array to zero
        }
    } // end default constructor

    //************************************
    //Specified constructor
    public IpAddress(String myAddress)
    {
        dottedDecimal = myAddress;
        String[] parsedOctets;
        parsedOctets = myAddress.split("\\Q.\\E"); // allows to stop at the dot
        for (i=0; i <=3; i++)
        {
            Octet[i] = Integer.parseInt(parsedOctets[i]); // breaking the string down to integers
        }
    }// end specified constructor

    //*****************************************************
    public String getDottedDecimal()
    {
        return dottedDecimal;
    }

    //*********************
    public int getOctet()
    {
        for (this.i=0; this.i <=3; this.i++)
        {
            return this.Octet[i];
        }
    }

} // end ip address class
```

Comment: what do you mean "las return statement"? Please provide more detail...

Comment: don't forget to click the checkmark to accept an answer...

Comment: Bob Kaufman already posted the solution. But I thought I would comment on thing. "i" should not ever be an instance variable. Instance variables should be used to store the state of an object. i is a counter used for iteration inside the methods. It has nothing to do with object itself. Instead you should do like this: "for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){ ... }". 

That way it is clear that the "i" is created specifically for iterating over that for loop. And no, it doesn't take more resources. In fact, it takes quite a bit less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want for that last method is this:

```
public int getOctet( int which )
{
    if ( which >= 0 && which <= 3 )
        return this.Octet[ which ];
    else
        return -1;  // error. Consider throwing an exception
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for I think i understand what you are saying, your saying in this statement that 0 thru 3 are acceptable because i only have objects in this array but anything else is a negative one cause it is false. I just learned this parseint stuff as well you guys are all awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like homework to me, but this is obviously not going to work:

```
public int getOctet()
{
    for (this.i=0; this.i <=3; this.i++)
    {
      return this.Octet[i];
    }

}
```

That will return from the function after the first iteration, you can't return from a function multiple times.

Comment: in some cases you could do a yield return if the return type were IEnumerable

Comment: Well, yes, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

For your last statement, you're running a loop that does nothing but return a value. It'll return the first time, but then the loop stops running, so the other returns don't do anything.

```
public int getOctet()
 {
     for (this.i=0; this.i <=3; this.i++)
        {
          return this.Octet[i];
        }

}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
          return this.Octet[0];
```

Since it only runs once.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the 'get octet' function, it will only ever return `Octet[0];`

The return statement stops execution of the function the first time it is hit.  What you really want is:

```
public int[] getOctet()
 {
          return this.Octet;
 }
```

Comment: this did not work i tried i think it was because  i was looking for an array. ooh rah great try i appreciated it alot.

Answer (score 0):

By naming your method `getOctect()`, it seems that you are hoping to return the array, not an individual int from within the array.  In that case, you should simplify it to something like this:

```
public int[] getOctet()
{
      return this.Octet;

}
```